# A Grid layout containing Card layouts - can it be done?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, grid-layout, cardlayout

The goal is to display a table of cells, where all cells are independent of one another, and each cell has several optional displays (Imagine a Kakuro board, jeopardy board, ext.)

It's my first attempt at swing. After a lot of reading, I decided that my approach will be to first design each cell independently using a Card Layout (this part I'm happy with), and then to 'wrap' it in a grid layout.
This is probably where my lack of understanding in basic Swing raises its head:

When designing each cell I create a frame and add a panel to it:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    public class Cell extends Component{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    /* we'll use a card layout with a panel for each look of the cell */
    CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    JPanel containterPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel thridpanel = new JPanel();

    public  Cell(){

        /* assign the card layout to the container panel */
        containterPanel.setLayout(cardLayout);

        /* assign objects to the different panels - details not important for the sake of the question */
        //....

        /* add the different panels to the container panel and show the initial one */
        containterPanel.add(firstPanel, "firstPanel");
        containterPanel.add(secondPanel, "secondPanel");
        containterPanel.add(thridpanel, "thridpanel");
        cardLayout.show(containterPanel, "firstPanel");

        /* add the container to the frame and display it*/
        frame.add(containterPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This behaves nicely.
But my attempt to wrap it in a grid layout where each cell behaves like this is very clumsy:

```
import java.awt.*;


public class Board{

    private static final int COLUMNS_NUM = 3;
    private static final int ROWS_NUM = 3;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    Cell cells[] = new Cell[COLUMNS_NUM * ROWS_NUM];

    public Board(){

        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS_NUM, COLUMNS_NUM));
        for (int i = 0; i <ROWS_NUM * COLUMNS_NUM; i++)
        {
            cells[i] = new Cell();
            panel.add(cells[i]);
        }

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Board();
    }

}
```

What I get is a bunch of unrelated frames, separated from the main board frame.
clearly I'm not handling the frames correctly (should I create only one..?).
Any help in guiding me to the correct approach will be appreciated.

Comment: 1) *"A Grid layout containing Card layouts - can it be done?"* Yes. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks @AndrewThompson, relatively new here- I made small edits, I believe it now holds the requirement of 'Minimal, complete and verifiable'. Please let me know if it's not.

Comment: If Cells are to be added to Board, make them a JPanel, not a JFrame

Comment: Generally, you draw a game board where the cells can take on different values.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and my Swing article, [Kakurasu Using Java Swing](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=795).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Cells are to be added to Board, make them a JPanel, not a JFrame

An example:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

//make it a sub class of JPanel for easier implementation. 
public class Cell extends JPanel{

    public  Cell(){

        JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
        //add a lable just so something is displayed
        firstPanel.add(new JLabel(("Panel 1"))); 
        JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel thridpanel = new JPanel();

        CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        /* assign the card layout */
        setLayout(cardLayout);
    
        /* add the different panels to the container panel and show the initial one */
        add(firstPanel, "firstPanel");
        add(secondPanel, "secondPanel");
        add(thridpanel, "thridpanel");
        cardLayout.show(this, "firstPanel");
    }
}
```

And a board to hold the cell:

```
    import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;


//make it a sub class of JFrame for easier implementation.
public class Board extends JFrame{

    private static final int COLUMNS_NUM = 3;
    private static final int ROWS_NUM = 3;

    Cell cells[] = new Cell[COLUMNS_NUM * ROWS_NUM];

    public Board(){

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        add(panel);  //or better    getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS_NUM, COLUMNS_NUM));

        for (int i = 0; i <(ROWS_NUM * COLUMNS_NUM); i++)
        {
            cells[i] = new Cell();
            panel.add(cells[i]);
        }

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Board();
    }
}
```

That is how it look like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that led me to the direction. 

In your suggestion, the Card Layout contains three panels, without a parent container - If I understand correctly, having such a container panel is the correct way to support transitions between cards. So what I did is this:
panel.add(cells[i].containterPanel);
instead of this:
panel.add(cells[i]);

That's all it took - adding the container panel and not the Cell itself (which, in my version, does not extends Jpanel).

Comment: I am glad it helped. Up voted you question because it was well formed.